# Navigating between sections in Beamer with CJK package

Tags: beamer, cjk, navigation

I am writing some slides using Beamer, and the slides contains UTF-8 characters. For example, here is a version without UTF-8 characters:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\begin{document}
% \begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}   % line 4
\section{Section 1}
\begin{frame}
    Section 1 Page 1
    % 中文                    % line 8
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    Section 1 Page 2
\end{frame}

\section{Section 2}
\begin{frame}
    Section 2 Page 3
    % 中文                    % line 17
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    Section 2 Page 4
\end{frame}
% \end{CJK}                 % line 20
\end{document}
```

The navigation on the bottom-right of the slides works perfectly. For example, the following two buttons on Page 1 goes to Page 3.

[image: 6th and 8th buttons on the bottom right]

However, if I uncomment line 4, 8, 17, and 20 to add some Chinese characters to the slides, these navigation buttons just goes to the last page (Page 4).

How can this problem be fixed? I want to avoid having `\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}` at the beginning of each frame and `\end{CJK}` at the end of each frame.

Comment: Try `\CJK{UTF8}{gbsn}` at the begin and `\endCJK` at the end.

Comment: This is the correct solution. Maybe you can make it an answer and I can accept it.

Comment: Closed because it has been answered and that was the solution, though the answerer chose to do it via a comment. Can be re-opened if the answerer would like to change that comment into an answer.